# Excel table formula where column name is taken from a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to figure out if and how the following is possible:

Imagine a Excel ListObject table with five columns

- first three are named Option 1, Option 2, Option 3 and contain arbitrary values
- fourth is labeled "Selection" and contains "Option 1", "Option 2" or "Option 3"
- fifth is labeled "Result" and should contain the value of the cell referenced by the cell labeled "Selection"

**Example:**

If Option 4, Option 7 and Option 3 contain 1, 2 and 3, respectively, and Selection is set to "Option 2", then Result should contain 7.

My approach was attempts via INDIRECT so far, but this does not seem to work. In particular, the following formula in the Result column

```
=INDIRECT("[@"&[@Selection]&"]")
```

results in an error. Is this not possible in general, or am I overcomplicating something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that indirect relative row referencing requires the inclusion of the table name:

`=INDIRECT("Table1[@["&[@Selection]&"]]")`

though I would avoid the **volatile** `INDIRECT` if possible, for example:

`=INDEX(Table1[@[Option 1]:[Option 3]],MATCH([@Selection],Table1[[#Headers],[Option 1]:[Option 3]],0))`

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine. One of the issues I may encounter is that the formula needs to be understood by, or at least provide the feeling of "I understand this! maybe...?" to, people who space out if they encounter a formula that spans more than one line :)